# Dropzone containsFiles not receiving an array

Tags: internet-explorer-11, dropzone

I am working on getting Dropzone setup on ie11. I appear to be running into an issue with the containsFiles function. The event that drops into that has a e.dataTransfers.types that is and object DOMStringList where it looks like it is expecting an array with the .some method.

Has anyone else ran into an issue when using Dropzone on ie11?

Thank you in advance. Here is the line I am running into issues 
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/dist/dropzone.js#L1341

Comment: Which version of Dropzone are you using? Please check [this document](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) and download the latest version, then according to the tutorials to use Dropzone library. I also tried to create a sample using Dropzone, it will show "object doesn't support property or method 'some'" error, perhaps this issue is related to the Dropzone library, you could post a [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/wikis/home).

Comment: We are using 5.7 from cdnjs https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/dropzone.js.

I was thinking I would need to report an issue but was hoping there was something dumb that I am doing.